# Select from two columns and merge them using Query in Google Sheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have two different colums with customers names and I need to select them showing the result in just one list, one list of customers after the other. How can I do it with a query in google sheet?

**I have this**

```
C  
Customer 1
Customer 2
Customer 3

D
Customer 3
Customer 4
Customer 5
```

**And I need this**

```
E
Customer 1
Customer 2
Customer 3
Customer 4
Customer 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you need a query for...

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({A2:A;B2:B}))
```

Adjust your ranges appropriately.